# How to get all the fields & their values in Json

Tags: item-web-api, field

I'm trying to get all the custom field names & their values, in a JSON string.

When I tried to serialize the item, it threw a StackOverflow exception:

```
JsonConvert.Serialize(item)
```

Then, I tried this:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> itemFieldsAndValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

///This condition to exclude Sitecore's default fields.
IEnumerable<Field> fields = item.Fields.Where(x=>!x.Name.StartsWith("__")); 

foreach(Field field in fields)
{
    itemFieldsAndValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(

        field.Name,
        item.Fields[field.Name].Value
    ));
}

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(itemFieldsAndValues);
```

Is there a better or faster way to achieve what I want.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second approach is absolutely correct.

There are 2 things you should be aware though:

1. With the code you included in your question you will not get fields that have no value, or fields that have only Standard Value defined. If you want to include them, you should call the following line before getting fields:

```
item.Fields.ReadAll();
```

Why? For performance reasons. You can read more about it here: [When is item.Fields.ReadAll() required to be run?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14594/when-is-item-fields-readall-required-to-be-run)

2. With the code you included you will get raw values of the fields. For fields like `Single-Line Text` or `Rich Text` it doesn't really matter, but for fields like `Image` you will get value like

```xml
<image mediaid="{648AFD6B-B750-45C9-AF8F-110B22F53454}" />
```

That's not necessarily what you need.

You may try using code like

```
var renderedFieldValue = Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FieldRenderer.Render(item, "Field Name");
```

but it really depends on what you want to do with the JSON data after you expose it.

---

**With all the above, be aware that there is already RESTful API for the ItemService in Sitecore**

If it's enabled in your website, you can use it with url like

> `https://localhost/sitecore/api/ssc/item/?path=/sitecore/content/home`

You can use item ID instead of path as well.

You can read more about it here https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html